# Can a Yemeni citizen travel through Oman airport with 2 airlines without visa?

Tags: transit, oman, airasia, yemeni-citizens

I am a Yemeni citizen traveling from Yemen to Malaysia but the flight goes like this :

From Yemen to Oman by Yemenia Airlines 
And then after 4 hours from Oman to Malaysia by Airasia

I don't have visa for Oman is that okay? This is not transit: it's two flights. As far as I know I have to pass the immigration check then get the baggage then I go to the departure and check in from there but how would I do that when I don't have visa?

Comment: What's your nationality? This makes a huge difference!

Comment: OP is a Yemeni citizen, based on his other question

Comment: Yes I am from Yemen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be fine.

For transits of less than 6 hours such as your case you don't need a visa, as long as you have proof of onward [travel](http://www.emirates.com/ca/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=YE&NV=Yemen&DC=MY&DV=Malaysia&TC=OM&TV=Oman&h=e0624f91437cbe2ccd93a227e7869b39c86281b), according to the Timatic tool on Emirates' website.

> **Transit - Oman (OM)   Visa**
>   Visa required.
>   **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
>   Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 6 hours.
>   **Visa Issuance:**
>   Passengers in transit for longer than 6 hours, can obtain a single transit visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 72
>   hours if they have confirmation from the airline that a visa has been
>   approved before departure.